# how i can know where a variable is a non-object before to try get something from this one

Tags: php

My problem is that want to know where a variable is a non-object before to try get something from this one ?

```
if( $something ){ //<-- here
    $somthing->doWhatever();
}else{
   //we can't do nothing because something is a non-object
   false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($something instanceof YourObject && method_exists($something, 'doWhatever')) {
    $something->doWhatever();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use is_object function

```
 if (!is_object($obj)) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [is-object](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-object.php), but is better use `instanceof` if you need be more strict.